# How much longer do I cook the roast?

Tags: baking, pork, roast

I was following the advice of preheating @ 400 and had every intention of lowering he temp to 300 but instead I forgot to lower it and ended up cooking it for the first 30mins at 400. I just lowered the temp to 300 and flipped it. How should I proceed?

Comment: You're likely done cooking by now, but the basic answer you'd get from most people here is: until the roast is at your desired internal temperature. Despite "rules of thumb" you'll see in many cookbooks and websites, there's really no formula to accurately predict how long to roast meat, as it will depend on size, shape, amount of fat or bone, etc.  A thermometer is the only way to achieve consistent doneness level.

Answer (score 1):

Without a thermometer (which I personally do not own), the other way of testing pork to make sure it is sufficiently cooked is to pierce it with a fork or skewer in the thickest part.

Check this extract from [recipetips.com](http://www.recipetips.com/kitchen-tips/t--461/pork-doneness.asp):

> Piercing: Another method for testing doneness is to prick the cut of pork with a fork or the tip of a knife and check to see if the juices that escape run clear. If the juices are clear or have just a very faint pink tint, the meat is done. If the juices are not clear, the meat should be returned to the heat source for further cooking.

Comment: that's better for something that's more steak-like.  It's more difficult to get a knife into the middle of the roast to extract whatever juices there might be.  (although it does work fairly well for chicken, if you get deep enough to the bone)